# How to return void in python

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

## This is the famous coin change dp problem - given some coins return possible amount 11=2+2+2+5

```
arr=[2,5]
def Recur(amount,seq):
    if amount==0:
        print(seq)
        return 
    if amount<0:
        return
    for coin in arr:
        seq+=str(coin)
        Recur(amount-coin,seq)


Recur(11,"")
```

Whatever I try to return the function returns one 2 more, that is it continues after the amount has reached 0. I tried to return 0,None, just return  -- nothing works? It always continues after <0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr=[2,5]
def Recur(amount,seq):
    if amount==0:
        print(seq)
        return 
    if amount<0:
        return
    for coin in arr:
        seq+=str(coin)  # error is in this line since you are 
                        #trying to update seq which persist across the method stack due 
                        #to for loop calls Recur method again with this updated seq 
                        #leading to extra addition of extra coin in seq.
        Recur(amount-coin,seq)


Recur(11,"")
```

You need to update seq across the call so that hence do following modification:

```
arr=[2,5]
def Recur(amount,seq):
    if amount==0:
        print(seq)
        return 
    if amount<0:
        return
    for coin in arr:
        Recur(amount-coin,seq+str(coin))


Recur(11,"")
```